# Построение графа, проблема сортировки пар

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка, графы, числа

Добрый день, помогите пожалуйста оптимально решить проблему.
Есть некий набор числовых пар [a, b], например

```
[0, 1], [3, 2], [4, 0], [3, 4], [2, 1], [9, 8], [10, 9], [8, 10]
```

В этом наборе есть n-количество закольцованных "цепочек" разной длины,
причем в каждой паре элементы a и b могут быть в произвольном порядке.

Собственно задача построить эти цепочки:

```
[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 0] и [8, 9], [9, 10], [10, 8]
```

Cкорее всего алгоритм заключается в построении графа, в котором числа это
вершины, а пары это ребра.

Буду признателен за любую помощь или совет.

Comment: ну это задача по сути о Эйлеровых циклах. Вот только разделить может быть немного не тривиально. И да, цепочки ВСЕГДА не пересекаются?

Comment: Да, цепочки никогда не пересекаются.
По сути, я и застрял на под-задачке, как разделить группы, поскольку каждая может быть неопределенной длины и количество самих цепочек плавующее.

Comment: а каждая вершина больше 2 раз хоть может быть?

Comment: Нет, не может. Речь идет о краях 3-х мерного объекта.

Comment: Не особо силен в алгоритмах, но задача похожа на построение графа, поиск компонент связности, и поиск цикла в каждой компоненте.

Comment: Это я и сам понимаю, вопрос как это сделать оптимально. Не через bruteforce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С учётом ответов из комментариев, задача стала крайне простой. Решение на C++.

```
int main() {
    map < int ,pair<int,int>> back;
    map <int, bool> used;
    int a,b;
    while (cin >>a >> b){
        if (!back.count(a))
            back[a] = make_pair(b,0);
        else back[a] = make_pair( back[a].first,  b);

        if (!back.count(b))
            back[b] = make_pair(a,0);
        else back[b] = make_pair( back[b].first,  a);       
    }

    for (auto x : back){
        auto R = x.first;   

        while (!used[R]){
            used[R] = true;
            cout << R<<" ";
            if (!used[back[R].first])
                R = back[R].first;
            else R = back[R].second;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Кстати, вы ребро [3,4] пропустили в условии. [Запускаемый пример](http://ideone.com/dAWHaB)

Идея простая - у нас всего один цикл в каждой компоненте, нам надо просто аккуратно по нему пройти.

Comment: Хм, интересно. Cейчас попробую.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю выходные данные: 0 : 1 4, 1 : 0 2, 2 : 3 1, 3 : 2 4, 4 : 0 3, 8 : 9 10, 9 : 8 10, 10 : 9 8 и  [0 1 2 3 4], [8 9 10].

Cкажем вершина 0: [1, 4]

Comment: @VVK да убрали бы эти строки) я их для вас оставил чтобы было понятно что где лежит http://ideone.com/dZclfq

Comment: Так как раз они меня совсем запутали

Comment: Я пока портирую Ваш кусок в JAVA, точнее в Processing. Обычно использую его для теоритических поисков.

Comment: Попробую разобрать под свои нужды http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/41graph/EulerianCycle.java.html, тем более сама книжка под рукой.

Comment: Разобрался. Огромное спасибо.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/leprous/2pna1fpx/3/

Comment: @VVK если ответ вам помог, примите его (нажав на галочку возле него)