# C++ std::map сортировка

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Как сортировать по признаку того что ключ данного элемента является значением другого? т.е надо сортировать по тому что значение первого является ключом второго ***std::map< sNode, sNode > test;*** И вообще можно ли так сделать?

Comment: Сортировать? Или сделать выборку таких элементов, что величины содержат ключ текущего элемента?

Comment: Что именно вы хотите сделать? `std::map` внутри строит дерево, сортируя ключи по признаку больше/меньше-равно. Если сортировать по признаку равно/не равно, то дерево очень глупое получится, в нем поиск медленный будет как перебор. Если вам нужна "двунаправленная" карта, то просто добавляйте пары и (k, v), и (v, k). Можете завернуть данные в структуры, где будет дополнительное поле, которое говорит, чем это изначально было, ключом или значением.

Comment: Предположим так:  берем ключ каждого и смотрим есть ли в мапе пара с значением = этому ключу. Если нет таких то это последний, берем значение его, и ищем среди ключей элементов, и так с каждым следующим найденным в цикле.

Comment: @Disastricks, а ну тогда просто берете вторую карту и не мучаете себе мозги.

Comment: почему последний, если начнем с рандомного то может не пройтись по всем

Comment: @Alexander Zonov, Да, но это как бы в 2 раза больше операций.

Comment: @Disastricks, все равно столько же операций неявных получится, а то и намного побольше, если делать так: **смотрим есть ли в мапе пара с значением = этому ключу**.

Comment: @Alexander Zonov, посмотрим, все же думаю поиск 1 раз по значению быстрее чем тыщу раз во второй мап добавлять.

Answer (score 1):

То, что вы хотите сделать, в общем случае может быть неразрешимо (например, при цикле - если у вас есть, скажем, пары (1,2) (2,3) (3,1) - какая должна быть первой?) или неоднозначно (например, (1,2) (2,3) (2,4)). Неясно, как обрабатывать вариант несвязанных пар - типа (1,2) (3,4) (5,6).

Но в принципе - рассматривая значения пар как вершины некоторого графа, а сами пары - как его ребра - вы получаете задачу [*топологической сортировки*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0), стандартной реализации в стандартной библиотеке C++ которой не имеется.

Но она достаточно легко [реализуется самостоятельно](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/topological_sort).

Comment: это не топологическая сортировка...  Это проще делается. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/669182/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80/669198#669198 Вот вроде бы ответ.

Comment: @pavel Тогда задача как минимум отвратно сформулирована...

Comment: да мне вообще кажется что как дубликат можно закрыть...